how to set custom color for statusbar text and icon in flutter?
i already tried with AnnotatedRegion but it's only change icon brightness light or dark i want to set my custom color for icon and text
@override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<SplashViewModelCubit, SplashViewModelState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
          return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
          value: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
              statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
              statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
              statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark),
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Container()
     );


I don't think that's possible. And it's not a Flutter thing. Even native apps can't change that

Does this answer your question? How to change status bar color in Flutter?
